# Postgresql: Need help replacing my programmatic solution with a pure SQL one (multi-column aggregates across several tables)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following three tables.

```
Customer
+----+------------+-----------+
| ID | First_Name | Last_Name |
+----+------------+-----------+

Purchase
+----+-----+-------+
| ID | VIN | PRICE |
+----+-----+-------+

Part
+-----+-----------+--------------+------+
| VIN | PART_NAME | ORDER_NUMBER | COST |
+-----+-----------+--------------+------+
```

For each customer, I need to find:

- The customer's name
- How many vehicles have been purchased from the customer.
- What is the average price of the vehicles purchased from the customer.
- What is the average number of parts that vehicles purchased from this customer need.
- What is the average cost of parts for vehicles purchased from this customer.

I'm currently working in Python and have been successful in using several queries, as well as frankly hacky python code, in order to arrive at the desired result. However, I would like to do as much of this with SQL as possible, since this is an assignment for an introductory database course.

1. First, I find the IDs of all customers from whom we have purchased vehicles, as well as the number of vehicles that have been purchased from them, and I store it in a list (CUSTOMER_LIST).

```
SELECT T1.ID, COUNT(*) 
FROM CUSTOMER AS T1, PURCHASE AS T2 
WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
GROUP BY T1.ID
```

2. For each ID in the list, I query for each customer's first and last names, and concatenate them, and append them to CUSTOMER_LIST.

```
SELECT CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' ', LAST_NAME)
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE ID = (CUSTOMER_LIST[0])
```

The list now holds the customer's ID, the number of vehicles sold, and their full name.

3. I then query for each vehicle purchased from the customer.

```
SELECT VIN
FROM PURCHASE
WHERE ID = (CUSTOMER_LIST[0])
```

4. For each vehicle purchased from this particular customer, I retrieve the total number of parts the vehicles needed, as well as the total cost of parts.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PART WHERE VIN = (VEHICLE_LIST[0])
SELECT SUM(COST) FROM PART WHERE VIN = (VEHICLE_LIST[0])
```

These values are divided by the number of vehicles purchased to arrive at the average number of parts and average cost of parts. The averages are appended to CUSTOMER_LIST.

5. Finally, I query for the average price of vehicles purchased from the customer.

```
SELECT to_char(AVG(PRICE), '9999999999D99') FROM PURCHASE WHERE ID = (CUSTOMER_LIST[0])
```

These values are also appended to CUSTOMER_LIST.

This sample data

```
+---------------+------------+-----------+
|      ID       | First_Name | Last_Name |
+---------------+------------+-----------+
| S530460864050 | JOHN       | SMITH     |
+---------------+------------+-----------+

+---------------+-------------------+-------+
|      ID       |        VIN        | PRICE |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+
| S530460864050 | 1GCHG39R5W1012259 |  2500 |
| S530460864050 | 1FD0X4HT5FEB20353 |  5000 |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+

+-------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------+-------+
|        VIN        |          PART_NAME          |     ORDER_NUMBER     | COST  |
+-------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------+-------+
| 1GCHG39R5W1012259 | Spark Plug Asm              | 1FD0X4HT5FEB20353-01 | 20.84 |
| 1GCHG39R5W1012259 | Filter Asm,Oil              | 1FD0X4HT5FEB20353-01 | 58.83 |
| 1GCHG39R5W1012259 | Switch Asm-Ignition & Start | 1FD0X4HT5FEB20353-01 | 13.72 |
| 1GCHG39R5W1012259 | Bearing Asm-Front Wheel     | 1FD0X4HT5FEB20353-02 | 61.52 |
| 1GCHG39R5W1012259 | Element-Air Cleaner         | 1FD0X4HT5FEB20353-02 | 21.85 |
```

Should result in the following

```
+------------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| Full Name  | Vehicles Sold | Average Cost of Vehicle | Average Number of Parts | Average Cost of Parts |
+------------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| JOHN SMITH |             2 |                 3750.00 |                     2.5 |                 35.35 |
+------------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
```

I arrive at the correct values with my solution, but the code isn't written in a way that's very intuitive or efficient, and I'd like to implement it entirely through SQL if possible.

Comment: There's one problem: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9592e902454d1660135ef5aeef172d66 In this fiddle you can see the count per vehicle and the average part costs. If you'd aggregate this result and calculate an avg, the result were 35.35/2, not 35.35 like it were done with avg part (5/2 instead of 5). Otherwise ist might be inconsistent, wouldn't it?

Comment: I think you're right in that I've been calculating average part costs incorrectly. I think it should be total parts cost/vehicles purchased, instead of average parts cost/vehicles purchased, though. That seems more similar to the way average parts per vehicle is calculated. What do you think?

Comment: I cannot help you :) I don't know your use case. But you should find a consistent form and update your question :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```sql
SELECT
  c.first_name || ' ' || c.last_name AS "Full Name", 
  COUNT(DISTINCT p.VIN) AS "Vehicles Sold", 
  AVG(p.PRICE) AS "Average Cost of Vehicle", 
  MAX(num_parts_per_vehicle * 1.00) / COUNT(DISTINCT p.VIN) AS "Average Number of Parts", 
  MAX(cost_parts_per_vehicle) AS "Average Cost of Parts"
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN purchase p ON c.ID = p.ID -- Get car info
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT p.id,
    -- avg parts per vehicle
    COUNT(pt.PART_NAME) / COUNT(DISTINCT p.VIN) AS num_parts_per_vehicle,
    -- avg cost per vehicle
    CAST(SUM(pt.COST) / COUNT(pt.ORDER_NUMBER) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS cost_parts_per_vehicle
  FROM purchase p
  INNER JOIN part pt ON p.VIN = pt.VIN
  GROUP BY 1 -- Get info per customer
) pt ON c.id = pt.id -- Get summarized parts info
GROUP BY c.first_name, c.last_name;
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6983d/71)

One potential issue I saw is the calculation of `Average number of parts` and `Average cost of parts` seem to be calculated different.  For number of parts, you have two cars and five parts which gives an average of 2.5.  For average cost, you have a total of $176.76 with five parts, which gives you an average of $35.35 and implies you are only counting one car.  It seems you are using different logic to calculate these two values.

Comment: I see what you mean about the average cost of parts. Since the average number of parts is calculated as total parts/vehicles purchased, then the average cost of parts should probably be total cost of parts/vehicles purchased.

Comment: Yep, makes sense to me.  Here's an updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6983d/82